# How to style a Button in Xamarin.Forms using CSS?

Tags: css, xaml, xamarin, button

I have added a button from xaml file like that:

```xml
<ContentView.Content>
   <Button Image="{Binding Icon}" Text="{Binding Title}" Clicked="ClickEvent" HeightRequest="10"  WidthRequest="10" />
</ContentView.Content>
```

How can I style the button to look like this?

[image]

I have css file in my xamarin project but I dont seem to reach Button image with it sucessfully because such code gives no result:

```css
.button img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

My current result of a button (terrible), picture is way to big:
[image: Too big icon]

Comment: If you're using XAML, then it's Xamarin.Forms. Apart from that, the styling options of CSS in Xamarin.Forms are quited limited. Did you follow the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/css/)?

Comment: Okay, so what should I use instead? Maybe any recommendations?

Comment: @ewerspej Thats exactly the tutorial I followed. But I need to get that button like in a picture. No idea what else to use

Comment: You could use an [ImageButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton) and set a `BorderRadius`, for example. Alternatively, you can also write your own Button component with an Image and a Label, surrounded by a Frame that has a `CornerRadius`.

Comment: Xamarin doesnt allow me to use component inside a button. I cannot write <Button><Image .../> <Label ... /> </Button>

Comment: Also, ImageButton lets me to click only on Image to handle click. But I want button with icon AND text

Comment: @ewerspej If you know how to create what I need please make an answer I will accet it as solution because I am really stuck on this and your answer is not cleasr for me yet :) thank you

Comment: Do you want or need to use CSS for some specific reason or is any solution acceptable for you?

Comment: @ewerspej just any solution that would give me something like in photo and I would be able to style thatbutton with image and text :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to fully customize a button like that, it's probably best to implement your own Button control instead of using CSS:

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourApp.Views.SomeRoundImageButton">

  <Frame
    CornerRadius="8">
    <Grid
      RowDefinitions="2*,*">
      <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
      <Label
        Grid.Row="1"
        TextColor="Blue"
        Text="{Binding Title}"/>      
    </Grid>
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer
        Tapped="OnButtonTapped"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
  </Frame>

</ContentView>
```

**Code-behind**

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace YourApp.Views {
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SomeRoundImageButton : ContentView {

        public string Title {
            get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public ImageSource Icon {
            get => (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty);
            set => SetValue(IconProperty, value);
        }

        public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ButtonTapped;

        public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(SomeRoundImageButton));
        public static readonly BindableProperty IconProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Icon), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(SomeRoundImageButton));

        public SomeRoundImageButton() {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void OnButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            ButtonTapped?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <views:SomeRoundImageButton
          Icon="{Binding Icon}"
          Title="{Binding Title}"
          WidthRequest="80"
          HeightRequest="80"
          ButtonTapped="Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

This gives you a lot more freedom for your design, you can make the Image bigger or smaller, add more lines of text to the Label, define the size of the `CornerRadius`, set all kinds of other properties...

Obviously, you need to play around with it to figure out the intended design, but I hope this will be of help. Note, this is just one way of doing this. In Xamarin.Forms (and .NET MAUI), there are many ways of achieving the same things.

Comment: Thank you it worked well. I only had to add WidthRequest and HeightRequest to Image :)